# Binary Search Method - how to find the mid point

Tags: algorithm, search, binary, point

Using a Binary search (which finds the mid point and discards the relevant list accordingly), I need to be certain about the **number of steps** and the **correct method** required to find the name 'TARYN' in the following list.

There are two methods shown below. Which is correct? I assumed the second...but am not sure. Could someone provide an explanation as to which method is most appropriate and why.

ANNE  BEN  CLIVE    DAVE ETHAN  GAL STEVE TARYN  REUBEN  YVONNE

**Method 1**

Stage 1: MP = (0+9)/2 = 4.5 = 4         Yes/no: NO

Discard 4 and less

Stage 2: MP = (5+9)/2 = 7       Yes/no: YES FOUND

How many steps did it take to find the element? **2**

---

**Method 2** (note that there are 10 elements)

Stage 1: MP = 10+1 / 2 = 5.5 = 6.

Stage 2: MP = 3+1  / 2  = 2 (Reuben)

Stage 3: MP = 1+1 / 2 = 1 (Taryn Found)

How many steps did it take to find the element? **3**

To put it differently, my assumption is that the first method is INCORRECT and the second method is correct. Could someone comment or clarify/justify?

Comment: Why did you round off ```4.5``` to ```4``` in Method 1 and ```5.5``` to ```6``` in method 2?

Comment: If you use method 2 you'll need to re-index the elements in the array, thus increasing space complexity

Comment: @SandeshGupta The OP is using round-half-to-even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even but good question, wonder why.....

Comment: `my assumption is that the first method is INCORRECT` (I see steps, not methods) *What* makes you assume each?

Comment: That's the question greybeard. The method taught is the second one (where you use the +1 ..this helps if the number of elements is odd, for example, and you round up). I have assumed, because this was the taught method, that was correct. The first was also suggested though ...and I haven't come across it before. Because they produce different outputs, I need to know ..

Comment: Note that in some cases (say if the number of elements was 7, and we were searching for the third element), the number of steps and output would be the same, regardless of which method was used.Students are advised that they can use ANY method as long as they are consistent, but if they produce different outcomes (and a different number of steps) surely this is incorrect.

Comment: (Isn't REUBEN out of place in the list?) You have to try all values with both methods to see if one method is better than the other.

Comment: `Because they produce different outputs` I don't see that (both find taryn). `if [methods use] a different number of steps [] surely this is incorrect` that just shows they are different. Using more of this resource or less of that is the point of algorithm analysis and code improvement.